# Should I remove unused services from the service container in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-2.1

I don't know if this has some benefits: should unused services be removed from the service container?

For example, in my bundle configuration I can disable the use of `lang` options provider:

```
my_bundle:
    providers:
        lang:
            enabled: false
```

When the `lang` provider is enabled, the `provider` tag should be added. This service is defined in `services.xml` file and loaded through the extension:

```xml
<service id="my_bundle.provider.lang" class="My\Provider\LangOptionsProvider">
```

So, it's a good idea to remove this definition and why?

```php
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    // ...

    $loader->load('services.xml'); // Loads "my_bundle.provider.lang"

    if($config['providers']['lang']['enabled']) {
        // lang provider is enabled, add the tag
        $container->getDefinition('my_bundle.provider.lang')->addTag('provider');
    }
    else { // Is this really needed?
        // Remove lang provider definition (or just the tag?!)
        $container->removeDefinition('my_bundle.provider.lang');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overhead is minimal because instantiation occurs when the service is requested, so it doesn't matter if you remove it or not.

> When you ask for the my_mailer service from the container, the container constructs the object and returns it. This is another major advantage of using the service container. Namely, a service is never constructed until it's needed. If you define a service and never use it on a request, the service is never created. This saves memory and increases the speed of your application. This also means that there's very little or no performance hit for defining lots of services. Services that are never used are never constructed.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html